# Why does the sour taste in yogurt increase with time?

Tags: flavor, fermentation, yogurt

If we let yogurt sit for more days, the yogurt becomes more and more sour. Why does that happen?

Answer (score 8):

Lactic acid is produced by 'probiotic' bacteria breaking lactose into lactic acid. Over time, more lactose is converted, producing more byproducts, thus more sourness.

The byproducts of this reaction are responsible for the distinctive flavor of yogurt.

See a more complete description here: [Lactic Acid Fermentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lactic_acid_fermentation)

Comment: For a more basic description, see here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curd#Formation

Comment: If you have something to add to your answer, please just edit it rather than adding a comment - it makes it easier for people to see!

Comment: whups! :-) didn't see the [edit] link, thank you

Comment: Lactic acid is, itself, sour -- you don't need "byproducts" to make it sour.

Answer (score 2):

Yogurt is sour because of the process of fermentation, whereby lactose bacteria make energy by breaking down lactose to glucose and galactose. Glucose then enter glycolysis to produce energy in a form of ATP and NADH, and lactic acid is produced as a by-product (waste product). The production of lactic acid makes the pH of the milk to drop, from approximately 6 to 4 and it is this lactic acid that makes yogurt sour.